# Android phone and Google glass usb communication

Tags: android, google-glass

I have developed two apps which communicates between `android phone` and `google glass` over USB cable. So that I have written two apps, one is `USB Host app` and another is `USB accessory app`. These two apps work fine for *mobile to mobile communication* and i have written an application for google glass as an accessory. But **Mobile and Google glass could not connect**. It shows me

```
04-26 12:18:55.041 529-742/? E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open /dev/usb_accessory
04-26 12:18:55.041 529-742/? E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open /dev/usb_accessory
```

If anyone can tell me, why do arise this error? it will worth for me.